# Elasticsearch script sort for missing fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run a script sort based on two values in my ES index. But ES throws the below exception. I tried adding if condition to avoid documents without these values but the script still seems to not work.

```
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(IndexName);
Script script = new Script("((doc['bio.stop'].value - doc['bio.start'].value));");
SortBuilder sizeSortBuilder = SortBuilders.scriptSort(script, ScriptSortBuilder.ScriptSortType.NUMBER);
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse matchAllResponse = client.search(searchRequest,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Exception:

```
"lang":"painless","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"A document doesn't have a value for a field! Use doc[<field>].size()==0 to check if a document is missing a field!"}
```

So i added if condition in the script to make sure ES does not fail. But sort is not working with this approach. Is the syntax correct for my intended use case.

```
 Script script = new Script(if(doc['bio.stop'].size() >0 && doc['bio.start'].size() >0) return (doc['bio.stop'].value - doc['bio.start'].value));
```

Comment: What makes you think that "sort is not working with this approach". Do you get another error?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the above script working with slight modification. Answer might help someone in future.

```
Script script = new Script("(doc['bio.stop'].size() >0 && doc['bio.start'].size() >0) ? (doc['bio.stop'].value - doc['bio.start'].value) : 0");
```